# Simple find command won't work. Error shows wrong foreign key

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to edit the content of a `Message` that already exists. So when I click:

```
 {{ HTML::linkAction('MessageController@edit', 'edit', array($message->PK_message)) }}
```

My 'MessageController'

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $message = Message::find($id);
    dd($message);

    // return Redirect::back();
}
```

I get this error message:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tblMessages.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `tblMessages` where `tblMessages`.`id` = {messages} limit 1)
```

What attracts my attention is that 'tblMessages.id' is not my Foreign key. 
So I think there's the problem?

Can I pass a custom Foreign key or is there another problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a different `Primary Key` other than `id` then you should explicitly declare the `$primaryKey` property like this:

```
class Message extends Model {

    // This is required now
    protected $primaryKey = 'PK_message';

}
```

By default, `Laravel` assumes (when not declared explicitly) `id` as primary key.

Comment: Damn, stupid I didn't thought about this.. :P Thanks!!